# How can I display the result of two table ordered by name with mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, each one has a column to identify the name, how can I make a query to display both table records order by name

```
companies
id | company
1  | maxxtor
2  | bhg

persons
id | company
1  | John Thorn
2  | Maria Smith
```

I want the output to be like:

```
2  | bhg
1  | John Thorn
2  | Maria Smith
1  | maxxtor
```

Comment: If that is the output you really want then : `SELECT * FROM companies UNION SELECT * FROM persons`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(All the following examples use `people` not `persons` as I wasn't paying attention, but I'm sure you will understand)

To answer you question simply use a `UNION` with a `ORDER BY`

```
select * from people
UNION
SELECT * from companies
ORDER by company
```

See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9e99/1

But you may want to think about how you are storing data, to have individual names in a column called company may not be the best way to create sustainable code.

It maybe useful to note that when `UNION` is used the column names from the first table are used for the subsequent table, so for example if you had the following ( http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b761/1 ):

```
CREATE TABLE people ( 
  id int auto_increment primary key, 
  name varchar(20)    
);
CREATE TABLE companies ( 
  id int auto_increment primary key, 
  company varchar(20)
);
```

You could use the following query and still have the same results:

```
SELECT * from people
UNION
SELECT * from companies
ORDER by name
```